# Difficulty understanding Apache JMeter results

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance

I'm new to performance testing and I was told by one of my teachers to use JMeter by Apache.

I have made a few tests but I do not entirely understand the results. 
My database is on my local host, if that makes any difference in interpreting these results.

I've been running a simple update query 10,000 times. Are these results fine?

I've been staring at the throughput and, KB/s and Avg. Bytes for a while. I'm not sure if these results are good or not. Average time is 1151 ms (1,15 seconds) which makes no sense.

If it takes 1.15 second to update once, how come 10,000 updates only took like 30 seconds?

[image: Test results]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using more than one virtual user? If you simulate 380 concurrent users and your average is 1.15 second you can be ready in around 30 seconds.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.